# Image segmentation in a grayscale image with close intensity levels?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, grayscale, image-segmentation

Here's the deal,
I'm trying to segment the capsicum at the lower centre of this image using MATLAB.
I tried intensity level slicing but the problem is that the intensity levels are too close. 
I tried stretching the histogram and then doing it but no luck.
Can someone help me?

[https://www.google.co.in/search?q=grayscale+image+matlab&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=0_aHU6HLL9iXuATIrIKADg&sqi=2&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=622#q=+matlab+flower+grayscale&tbm=isch&facrc=*&imgdii=*&imgrc=aWRqU-vBISjI3M%253A%3BFy0FnGZTpyzSzM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.cs.tut.fi%252F~foi%252FGCF-BM3D%252Fimages%252Fpeppers256_est_s15.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.cs.tut.fi%252F~foi%252FGCF-BM3D%252F%3B256%3B256](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=grayscale+image+matlab&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=0_aHU6HLL9iXuATIrIKADg&sqi=2&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=622#q=+matlab+flower+grayscale&tbm=isch&facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=aWRqU-vBISjI3M%253A%3BFy0FnGZTpyzSzM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.cs.tut.fi%252F~foi%252FGCF-BM3D%252Fimages%252Fpeppers256_est_s15.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.cs.tut.fi%252F~foi%252FGCF-BM3D%252F%3B256%3B256)

Comment: Show us some code as to what you have tried.  Also, doing intensity slicing will be difficult.  I would suggest you do some sort of edge detection, then some region filling.

Comment: Hava a look at this [example](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/images/examples/marker-controlled-watershed-segmentation.html?prodcode=IP&language=en).

Comment: Do you know about histogram equalization? It stretches the gray scale values to full band

Comment: Yes I know. I'm not able to post the actual image and unable to find it on internet. This was just something similar. I've tried all this.

Comment: How about something based on [watershed](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/images/examples/marker-controlled-watershed-segmentation.html)